# Adding a View All class to Kaminari Pagination

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently using the Kaminari gem for my pagination. I was wondering 
what the best way to add a `.view_all` class/view would be? If anyone has done this 
and could lend some assistance it would be appreciated.